# Ontouch of two imageButtons at the same time

Tags: android

I have two image-buttons on my layout I have to handle three cases 
1.button 1 get touched 
2. Button 2 get touched 
3. button 1 and 2 both touched at the same time

In my OntouchListner  I have cached the first two cases But how to catch the 3rd  one ? please Help me...

Comment: Are these over lapping or are you looking for multitouch? What device are you using to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just catch one. :S in your case two but it's hardware or software dependencie.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply In my game there  are two image buttons on a canvas and separated by particular distance.  User clicks/taps these buttons continuously and I have to listen for these touch events